# How to migrate users to a new account

Tags: website-design, users

I was wondering if you know any benchmarks for a process that requires user migration from one account to another.
We already have users that have been registered for a long time on our website, but we are chaning the registration process and whole backend and we need to migrate these long-term users to new accounts.
How would you handle this situation?
Would you build a pop-up, a landing page, floating button? Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Have a look at how Google transitions their products and takes you to new interfaces. Along with it, it asks for acceptation of updated privacy policy or any other details.

Answer (score 2):

Email them notification that the account system is changing. Perhaps send a second email as the date gets closer.

If they come to the site and login with the old account, immediately redirect them to the new account.

I think the big thing here is that if possible re-use the information you have. Remove the requirement of them filling a new form in again if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, guys.
The problem is we have to have completely new registration form as we are using new backend.
I was wondering if this is a good idea: a user logs into old account and after the log he ends up in a quasi-landing page informing him about the new version and its features. User would be able to come back to the older version. When we know the exact date of migration we will to include a clock that informs them how much time they have before the deadline.

Another idea is that a user that logs in to an older version sees a huge pop-up with all the perks of new registration/account.